# Why does Text = null?

Tags: android, null

I am new to Android and Java and don't know why the Text value is null after I assign Text to it? This is a project for University They didn't teach us Java only gave us Eclipse and Android Sdk and Java need some help please!

```
package com.example.glossaryapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Syntax extends Activity {

static String Text;
public static TextItem[] Syntax = new TextItem[50];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.syntax);

    final TextView show = (TextView) Syntax.this
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewSyn);

    // Linking the text View widget

    int Count1 = 0;

    // Using the TextView's shows method set text to display the appropriate
    // arrays and indexes

    if (Syntax[0] != null) {

        Text = Syntax[0].displayText();
        show.setText(Text);
    }

    // The Add button for if a user wants to add a new TextItem to the Array
    Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butAddSyntax);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Create.strSender = "Syntax1";

            startActivity(new Intent(Syntax.this, Create.class));

        }// end of on click
    });// butAddSyntax

    // Home Button
    Button but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttHomeSyntax);
    but2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();

        }// end of on click
    });// buttonHomeSyntax

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    TextView show = (TextView) Syntax.this.findViewById(R.id.textViewSyn);

    if (Syntax[0] != null) {

        Text = Syntax[0].displayText().toString();
        show.setText(Text);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is null? static String Text;?

Comment: It's wrong of them to force you to start with Android. You should study some basic Java in parallel. It'll save you time.

Comment: You never assign a text to Syntax[0]

Comment: Also, variable names start with a lowercase letter (by convention)

Comment: @MAcro: Yes the static string Text was null because it was declared outside the button I think

Comment: KEYSER Thank you for your help will remember next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android's LogCat will help you to solve this kind of problems.

Here you have a nice article:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html

I think the problem is in here:

```
if( Syntax[0] != null ){
    Text = Syntax[0].displayText();
    show.setText(Text);
}
```

you could begin using LogCat trying this:

```
if( Syntax[0] != null ){
    Log.d("MyApp", "Sintax (0) = " + Syntax[0].displayText());
    Text = Syntax[0].displayText();
    show.setText(Text);
} else Log.d("MyApp", "Nothing ");
```

And watch the result in the Logcat pane.

Comment: Thanks Gyss I used the Log cat and the debugger and found that if statement to be the problem thank you so much for your help.